# Hello Program in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I'm getting 404 error while running the below code,kindly help.  everything looks fine here,but i'm still getting 404 error.kindly help me to resolve this.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
      <display-name>Hello Spring</display-name>

          <servlet>
          <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
          </servlet>
          <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
            <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
          </welcome-file-list>
          </web-app><br/>
```

hello-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan basepackage="com.hello"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResouceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
</beans></br>
```

HelloController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView getHello()
    {
        return new ModelAndView("hellopage","hellomessage","Welcome Spring MVC!!!");
    }

}</br>
```

hellopage

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>${hellomessage}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which version of spring jars you are using ??

Comment: what is your project name and controller class package name ??

Comment: Found http://www.tutorialsdesk.com/2016/01/spring-mvc-hello-world-tutorial-with.html example on web for Spring MVC Hello World example

Comment: HelloMVC is my project name & HelloController is the controller,com.hello is my package.4.0.6 is my jar versions

Comment: So your URL would be HelloMVC/hello, are you hitting the same ?

Comment: I have my libraries into Javaresources folder is that wrong?when I try to paste into Web-inf lib it throws error.

Comment: Yes im hitting the same,

Comment: Yes you need to keep libraries in your WEB-INF/lib folder

Answer (score 0):

For Spring 4.x.x , no need to mention version in dispatcher-servlet config's `<beans xsi:schemaLocation"">` (hello-servlet.xml in your case ) Please, Update as per below.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

 <context:component-scan basepackage="com.hello"/>

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResouceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
 </bean>
 </beans>
```

Comment: Have you placed jars in WEB-INF/lib folder ?

Comment: Also it's not InternalViewResolver, change it to InternalResouceViewResolver

Comment: I couldn't move the jars to webinf folder lib,please help

Comment: Are you using eclipse ?? If so Open Workspace from file explorer and than copy and paste jars to lib folder

Comment: Follow this http://www.tutorialsdesk.com/2016/01/spring-mvc-hello-world-tutorial-with.html there is step by step solution, I hope it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

What if you start with Spring-Boot? You can without effort start with the Spring that will build and confiure everything for you from the scratch. Here is the Start point for the Example you'r looking for:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html

You can also Download the Spring Tool Suite and create a new Project from Example to learn how to do that. There are many nice tutorials there :)

I hope that helps!

Regards